# Volume of a solid.

Tags: calculus, integration, geometry

A curve has equation $y=\frac{x^2}{2x+1}$. The region bounded by the curve, the $x$-axis between $x=0$ and $x=1$ and the line $x=1$ is rotated through one revolution about the $x$=axis to form a solid with volume $V$. Using the substitution $u=2x+1$, or otherwise, show that $$V=\frac{\pi}{24}(4-3\ln 3)$$.

Can anyone explain it? I can't imagine the thing out.

Comment: Did you succeed in writing down an integral for the volume? Is it then evaluation of the integral that gave trouble?

Comment: Look here:https://www.khanacademy.org/math/integral-calculus/solid_revolution_topic/disc-method/v/disk-method-around-x-axis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Integrating with disks, you have that any one disk has volume $V_\text{disk}=\pi r^2h$, where $r$ denotes the radius and $h$ the height. For each disk, $r$ is determined by the vertical distance between the curve $y=\dfrac{x^2}{2x+1}$ and the axis of revolution $y=0$, which means $r=\dfrac{x^2}{2x+1}-0=\dfrac{x^2}{2x+1}$. The height $h$ is taken into account when integrating in the form of the differential $\mathrm{d}x$. Putting all this together, you have
$$V=\pi\int_0^1 \left(\frac{x^2}{2x+1}\right)^2\,\mathrm{d}x$$
As the hint suggests, substituting $z=2x+1$ is a viable option. This gives $\mathrm{d}z=2\,\mathrm{d}x$, and so the integral becomes
$$V=\frac{\pi}{2}\int_1^3 \left(\frac{\frac{z-1}{2}}{z}\right)^2\,\mathrm{d}z=\frac{\pi}{8}\int_1^3\frac{(z-1)^2}{z^2}\,\mathrm{d}z$$